# Inline variables lifetime

Tags: c++, c++20

Do inline variables have some defined initialization/destruction order like regular non-static class members, for example?

Assume I have inline variable `b` that depends on inline variable `a`:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A() : p(std::make_shared<int>(5)) {}

    std::shared_ptr<int> p;
};

struct B
{
    B(A& a) : p(a.p.get()) { func(); }

    ~B() { func(); }

    void func() { std::cout << *p; }

    int* p;
};

inline A a;
inline B b(a);

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

My understanding was that `a` and `b` should not be instantiated, because they are not referenced, but surprisingly this code prints `55` with both MSVC2022 and GCC12. And even if I do this:

```
class C
{
public:

    static inline A a;
    static inline B b = B(a);
};
```

I get the same result.

1. Is it guaranteed that `b` is created after `a` and is destroyed before `a`?
2. Are inline variables always instantiated even if they are not referenced?
3. What if I remove `inline` in the first code sample? What changes?
4. What will happen if `a` and `b` are in different translation units?

Comment: 1. Yes, in a single transaction unit. 2. No, they have side effects, can't be removed. 3. Nothing. 4. See 1.

Comment: I'm curious where the idea comes from that unused inline variables are not initialized. I understand them to be basically header-only global variables and so they need the same kind of linkage as inline functions to avoid duplicates.

Comment: `inline B b(a);`, I'd recommend `inline B b{a};` or `inline B b = a;` syntax, to make it more clear it is a global variable and not a function. Or even `inline auto b = B{a};`